# How to not overwrite the reference if it has an existing record in database everytime I update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement an edit button to my project but everytime I update the existing record it keeps overwriting the existing Reference ID. My problem is how to not overwrite the existing Reference ID if it has a existing record?

I tried this but not working

```
public IActionResult Edit(string? Reference, RFSL Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existingModel = _dbcontext.Reim.Find(Reference); 

        if (existingModel != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingModel.Reference))
        {
            Model.Reference = existingModel.Reference;    
        }

        _dbcontext.Reim.Update(Model);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        GlobalVar.ID = Model.ID;
        var tranComp = Model.ID;

        return Redirect("~/RFS/EntryFormDetails?ID=" + GlobalVar.ID);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. You could never edit the Entity.Reference if this worked as expected.

Comment: I'd also recommend to use DTOs instead of directly passing around DB Entities.

Comment: Oh, ... I see ... I think you are tricking the change tracker. Get the entity from db (that part is ok), **then apply requested changes to _it_**, so changes are actually tracked. Then call `_dbcontext.Reim.Update(existingModel);`. If above `existingModel is null` I'd return a `NotFound` because it doesn't make sense to _update_ a non-existing entity, except this shall be designed as "upsert", in which case you need to insert, not update if the entity couldn't be found.

Comment: ^^ This assumes you are using Entity Framework (Core?). But you didn't tag it. So, if you don't then the comment is somewhat wrong, but may be applicable to other ORMs as well.